# Docker compose connection issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I try to run a rails application in docker but I have an issue with docker-compose network, I think...

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM ruby:2.3-slim

RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -qq -y --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    nodejs \
    libpq-dev \
    git \
    tzdata \
    libxml2-dev \
    libxslt-dev \
    ssh \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV APP_HOME /var/apps/books-store
RUN mkdir -p $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

ENV GEM_HOME /var/apps/books-store/vendor/bundle
ENV PATH $GEM_HOME/bin:$PATH
ENV BUNDLE_PATH $GEM_HOME
ENV BUNDLE_BIN $BUNDLE_PATH/bin

EXPOSE 3000
```

my docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  database:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/pgdata:/pgdata
    ports:
      - '5555:5432'
    env_file:
      - '.env'
  web:
    links:
      - database
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/var/apps/books-store
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    command: [bundle, exec, puma]
    env_file:
      - '.env'
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

When I try `docker-compose up`, from logs I see rails server starts successfully but when I try to access localhost:3000 from host browser it does not work and I could not understand why. What am I doing wrong?

docker ps:

```
407b59a2fa99   bookstore_web   "bundle exec puma"      About a minute ago  Up 41 seconds  0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp  bookstore_web
1837fc3e3f387  postgres        "docker-entrypoint..."  About a minute ago  Up 49 seconds  0.0.0.0:5555->5432/tcp  bookstore_database_1
```

docker-compose logs web:

```
Attaching to bookstore_web_1
web_1 | Puma starting in single mode...
web_1 | * Version 3.6.2 (ruby 2.3.3-p222), codename: Sleepy Sunday Serenity
web_1 | * Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
web_1 | * Environment: development
web_1 | * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:9292
web_1 | Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

Comment: What version of docker are you running, and on what platform? What is `$DOCKER_HOST` set to? What does `docker-compose logs` show? Is port 3000 open inside the container (test with a docker exec into the container and a curl to localhost)?

Comment: Your docker-compose.yml is binding on port 3000, but your web container log says it is listening on port 9292.

Comment: That was the problem. Right now is working. Thanks a lot for your help :d